# add HTTP to url

Tags: php, string, url

I have a function which is used to add an `http://` to a url,which do not have a `http://` like as below

```
function addhttp($url) {
 if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
      $url = "http://" . $url;
  }

return $url;
}
```

My problem is ,

If i pass a url with `&`,the string after the `&` will skipped,
eg:
    https://www.example.com/Welcome/Default.aspx?scenarioID=360&pid=3308&treeid=1000
Returns

https://www.example.com/Welcome/Default.aspx?scenarioID=360

I lose `&pid=3308&treeid=1000` this part,How to fix this error??

Comment: I returns correctly, but how and where are you passing the url?

Comment: This is actually a codeigniter function, and this will be like  $url            =$this->addhttp($_GET['u']);

Comment: hmm ok, but I'm really not losing anything when I run your code. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67eb0e9fe39041db0ebb51ea975daa7fa424f818

Comment: I realize that $_GET['u'] returns only  https://www.example.com/Welcome/Default.aspx?scenarioID=360 .that was the problem

Comment: yes, since after the `&` is another pair. Maybe you should get the query after the `?`

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan  $extra_params  = $this->input->get();
        unset($extra_params['u']);
        if(!empty($extra_params)){
            foreach($extra_params as $key => $data)
         {
            $url.='&'.$key.'='.$data;
         } 
        } This code fix my error,but is this a good logic?

Comment: It cost you another lines of code. If you can get the current url using code igniter, you can then use `parse_url` when getting the query. You can check it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce the error using PHP 5.5. However, personally I don't like to use a regular expression when there are built in functions that do the job. The following should work just fine as a replacement for the regular expression `~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i`:

```
<?php
function addhttp($url, $https=false) {
    $protocols = ['https://', 'http://', 'ftps://', 'ftp://'];
    $heystack = strtolower(substr($url, 0, 8));
    foreach ($protocols as $protocol) {
        if (strpos($heystack, $protocol) === 0) {
            return $url;
        }
    }
    return ($https ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $url;
}

$url = 'www.example.com/Welcome/Default.aspx?scenarioID=360&pid=3308&treeid=1000';
// for http://
echo addhttp($url); 
// for https://
echo addhttp($url, true);
```

I added an optional parameter here, if you don't like it just take it out and remove the ternary expression `(<expression> ? true : false)`.

If you need to get the value of the `URL` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Another builtin function would be `parse_url('google.be', PHP_URL_SCHEME) !== null`

Comment: Yeah, good call @DarkBee. But it looks like there is a change in behaviour to the function post PHP 5.4.7 specific to the scheme portion of the URL being absent or not. check out the second example on the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php